# What's a word for "shout" but to convey excitement?

Tags: word-request

Example sentence:

> "What a great idea!" I __.

I searched for synonyms for [blurt](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/blurt?s=t). Exclaim comes close, but it doesn't have a positive tone, I think. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the word **exclaim** because it can have either a positive or negative connotation depending on the context in which it is used.

Also, keep in mind that the tone of your voice is very important as it can express different feelings.

Please also understand that behind the words there's a certain informatic and energy load. Information is the transmission of the message to the cognitive level whereas the energy is the inner feeling of whatever we want to convey.

Answer (score 2):

**Cheer** or **Whoop** can be used in such contexts.

Also, words that depict sounds, referred to as Onomatopoeia(s), such as Yipee, Hurray can also be used to show such expressions, if the sentence-structure allows.

One thing to note, 
*Exclaim* does  not only conveys a negative feeling, such as of fear etc., but it can be used for to convey Excitement.